# DbContext.Model.Max(O => O.XXX) in EF 6 Return Wrong Value

Tags: entity-framework

im trying to get max value from EF 6 
but it just return the first row in my table not the max value

```
string LastKode = db.barang.Max(Bg => Bg.no_brg).ToString();
```

ASPX MVC5 EF6 Project 
In Visual Studio 2013 Express Preview

Comment: Can you provide more details, like the schema of the table?